# In node.js, trying to group several messages using underscore, but don't know how to parse it

Tags: node.js, underscore.js

I am using node.js and redis to receive messages in json, the message in plain test is like this

```
362S29MM09 36072 36071 ARRIVAL ARRIVAL ON TIME
362S29MM09 36075 36072 DEPARTURE DEPARTURE LATE
362K27MM09 36052 36050 ARRIVAL ARRIVAL ON TIME
```

Note that the first and second message are the same, so I wish to group these message by the first field, I use the underscore to group the message, but I don't know how to parse the grouped message.

```
{'type':362S29MM09,'st1':36072 ,'st2':36071 ,'event':ARRIVAL,'next_event':ARRIVAL,'status':LATE}

var groups =  underscore.groupBy(msg, function(obj){ return  obj.train_id}) ;   
console.log(groups);
```

but it only shows

```
{ undefined:
   [ { header: [Object], body: [Object] },
     { header: [Object], body: [Object] },
     { header: [Object], body: [Object] } ] }
```

How can I further parse the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what your actual question is (you're grouping on `train_id` which doesn't exist, and where do `header` and `body` come from?).

If you want grouping on `type`, you can use something like this:

```
var underscore = require('underscore');

var msgs = [ 
{'type':'362S29MM09','st1':36072 ,'st2':36071 ,'event':'ARRIVAL','next_event':'ARRIVAL','status':'ON TIME'},
{'type':'362S29MM09','st1':36075 ,'st2':36072 ,'event':'DEPARTURE','next_event':'DEPARTURE','status':'LATE'},
{'type':'362K27MM09','st1':36052 ,'st2':36050 ,'event':'ARRIVAL','next_event':'ARRIVAL','status':'ON TIME'}
];

var groups = underscore.groupBy(msgs, function(obj){ return obj.type; }) ; 
console.log(groups);
```

Which results in this output:

```
{ '362S29MM09': 
   [ { type: '362S29MM09',
       st1: 36072,
       st2: 36071,
       event: 'ARRIVAL',
       next_event: 'ARRIVAL',
       status: 'ON TIME' },
     { type: '362S29MM09',
       st1: 36075,
       st2: 36072,
       event: 'DEPARTURE',
       next_event: 'DEPARTURE',
       status: 'LATE' } ],
  '362K27MM09': 
   [ { type: '362K27MM09',
       st1: 36052,
       st2: 36050,
       event: 'ARRIVAL',
       next_event: 'ARRIVAL',
       status: 'ON TIME' } ] }
```